# Simple python loop over a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to loop trough this dictionary in Python, and print key and the value, I'm a newbie in Python and the examples found on the internet doesn't work or print errors.

So how could I loop the below table properly and display key/value?

```
letters = {
    "m":1, "n":1, "r":1, "M":1, "N":1, "R":1, "l":1, "L":1, "1":1,
    "3":1, "6":1, "7":1, "8":1, "0":1,
}
```

Comment: http://www.littletechtips.com/2009/10/python-101-how-to-iterate.html

Comment: You should be working through a tutorial, which would cover this :). The official tutorial (http://docs.python.org/tut) is good if you know another programming language, which it sounds like you do. If you want something slower paced, people seem to like [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org). Cheers.

Comment: "Don't work" -- do you use Python 3.x?

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/ and http://whathaveyoutried.com/.

Comment: @Marcin No, thanks. The fact someone is brainless is not my fault.

Comment: @phant0m I dont know,lol

Comment: @Scott It's your fault that you can't write a good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use items(), e.g.:

```
for k, v in letters.items():
  print k,v
```

or since it's a dictionary, iterate over the keys, e.g.:

```
# uses iterator, as opposed to returning all the keys via .keys()
for k in letters:
  print k, letters[k]
```

Comment: +1 iterator is more idiomatic in Python

Comment: There is `dict.iteritems`, you don't need to pull the values out yourself.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) in python.

```
for k, v in letters.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this

```
# for key in letters
# for key in letters.iterkeys()
for key in letters.keys():
    print key, letters[key]

# for key, val in letters.iteritems()
for key, val in letters.items():
    print key, val
```